# Json_table in AS400

Tags: ibm-midrange

I am using the below sql query with json but i am unable to retrieve the data , 0 rows retrieved and 100 record not found error i am getting. Any suggestions

```
select *                                                                  
  from json_table('"fetchData":[{
    "vehicleIdOutput":8005451,
    "sequenceNumberOutput":0}]',
    '$' 
     COLUMNS ( nested '$.fetchdata[*]'                                                         
     columns (  vehicleIdOutput  decimal(7, 0) PATH '$..vehicleIdOutput',           
       sequenceNumberOutput decimal(7, 0) PATH '$..sequenceNumberOutput'  
      ) )) as t;
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `error on error` to see that DB2 does'nt see your input as valid JSON

```
select *                                                                  
  from json_table('"fetchData":[{
    "vehicleIdOutput":8005451,
    "sequenceNumberOutput":0}]',
    '$' 
     COLUMNS ( nested '$.fetchdata[*]'                                                         
     columns (  vehicleIdOutput  decimal(7, 0) PATH '$..vehicleIdOutput',           
       sequenceNumberOutput decimal(7, 0) PATH '$..sequenceNumberOutput'  
      ) )
      error on error) as t;
```

You can either use curly brackets to tell the outermost thing is an object

```
select *                                                                  
  from json_table('{"fetchData":[{
    "vehicleIdOutput":8005451,
    "sequenceNumberOutput":0}]}',
    '$.fetchData'
     COLUMNS (
        vehicleIdOutput decimal(7, 0) path '$.vehicleIdOutput',
        sequenceNumberOutput decimal(7, 0) path '$.sequenceNumberOutput'
        )
      error on error ) as t;
```

or remove `fetchData` and directly use the array

```
select *                                                                  
  from json_table('[{
    "vehicleIdOutput":8005451,
    "sequenceNumberOutput":0}]',
    '$'
     COLUMNS (
        vehicleIdOutput decimal(7, 0) path '$.vehicleIdOutput',
        sequenceNumberOutput decimal(7, 0) path '$.sequenceNumberOutput'
        )
      error on error ) as t;
```